# Change opacity on part of a geom_bar object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the opacity of a ggplot bar plot. Consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(period = rep(c("current", "past"), 3), 
                 type = c("so_far", "so_far", "source_x", "source_x", "source_y", "source_y"), 
                 income = c(12, 10, 7, 9, 4, 7))
ggplot(df, aes(x = period, y = income, fill = type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This gives the following plot:
[image]

In reality though for the current period source_x and source_y are estimates, while in the past they are true values. So I want to alter the opacity of just the blue and green portions on the left side bar. 
Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dotted-line border might work better here to highlight the bar sections containing estimates. In the code below, I've used both linetype and alpha aesthetics to mark the two bar sections that are estimated. I've also reversed the legend so that the color order corresponds to the color order of the stacked bars.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = period, y = income, fill = type, 
               linetype=ifelse(grepl("current", period) & grepl("source", type), "B", "A"),
               alpha=ifelse(grepl("current", period) & grepl("source", type), 0, 1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", lwd=0.5, colour="grey40") +
  scale_alpha(range=c(0.5,1)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  guides(alpha=FALSE, linetype=FALSE,
         fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

[image]